# Docker Image of kibana using openjdk:8 as base image

Tags: docker, kibana

I want to create a docker image for standalone kibana using base image as openjdk:8

Any suggestions or links??

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely and that makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions.

Comment: Also Kibana is a Node.js application. I doubt you want `openjdk:8` for the base image.

Comment: I have created a docker image of kibana on top of openjdk:8 , but now i want to parameterize elasticsearch.username and elasticsearch.password in kibana.yml , which is getting mounted during building image. currently i have hardcoded these 2 values inside my kibana.yml